# What happened to Kushina's soul

Tags: naruto

During the 9 tails attack on the hidden leaf, Minato along with Kushina performed the death reaper sealing jutsu and sealed the Kyuubi into Naruto. Its been known that those who perform this forbidden sealing jutsu sacrifice both their lives and souls to the death reaper. However, Minato said he would also seal part of Kushina inside Naruto (which he actually did).

Does this mean that half of Kushina's soul was sealed in Naruto while the death reaper took the remaining half? Or were both hers and Minato's taken by the death reaper.

Comment: Kushina didn't perform the jutsu. The only thing she did was to subdue the Kyūbi with her chains and when he broke free shield Naruto with her body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special happened to Kushina's soul, she died from having Kurama extracted from her body and the wounds inflicted during the battle with Kurama.

Minato used the Death Reaper on himself to seal away the half of Kurama that he had stored in himself. The other half got sealed in Naruto and Minato infused the Eight Trigrams Sealing jutsu with his own and Kushina's chakra.

Here you can find the scene where Kushina tells Naruto that Minato had infused her chakra into the seal: https://youtu.be/D3tJoGr6pp4?t=68

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear.

There are many instances in Naruto when the souls come to the rescue-Dan coming to save Tsunade vs Madara,Obito coming back to help Kakashi and so on.

The only possible explanation of these souls flying about is that they probably get a chance to go back to the real life once and help their friend out,or so as it seems.

Now,Kushina only helped Naruto to subdue Kurama(as the comment says).Kushina was not sealed inside of Naruto.If she had been,Kurama would have already sensed her presence.She came back from the afterlife to help Naruto.

If this doesn't even help,then it's probably a translation issue which mixes up the real meanings.But Kushina was DEFINITELY NOT sealed inside Naruto.

Comment: I thouhgt part of her chakra was put into the seal that was used to seal Kurama in Naruto. That's why she appeared when he was trying to "tame" him. Just like how Minato sealed his own chakra in there to re-seal Kurama after the seal would have been broken (fight against Pain)

Comment: I don't remember any instances of Kushina being sealed in Naruto.Minato was only there because he had the other part of Kurama,so maybe somehow(unclear)he could have helped Naruto.

Comment: Minato sealed part of both Kushina's and his own chakra into Naruto when they sealed Kurama in him. http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kushina_Uzumaki Check the last paragraph about her background: "Minato then sealed the rest of their remaining chakra into Naruto." Also, Minato has the other half of Kurama sealed in him but that can't be the reason why Minato appeared to help Naruto since he sealed himself with the Death Reaper Seal after that and there is no escape from 'that dimension' so to say.

Comment: What dimension?It's afterlife bruh.Anything can happen.The Wikia is not always correct too.Its purely based on self interpretation.Its not official,it has been written by someone else

Comment: I just called it a dimension because I didn't know what else to call it. :-p Also, it's not just afterlife because those that have been sealed with the death reaper seal cannot be summoned with Edo Tensei. Otherwise Kabuto would have definitely used the hokages in the 4th Great Ninja War. I will check for references regarding the sealing of Minato's and Kushina's chakra in Naruto's seal later since I don't have a lot of time atm.

Comment: Found it, Kushina literally says it herself: https://youtu.be/D3tJoGr6pp4?t=68